# iOS App Store - Individual account , Multiple Company Names

Tags: ios, app-store

I have several apps in the App Store under a certain company name under an individual account.
When I do a search for my apps, I can see

-Name of App

-Company Name that I entered

As I'm doing some other apps under another company name with a partner, am I able to add the new apps to this same account, and have the apps display another company name?

-Name of New App

-2nd Company Name

Or do I have to get another individual account in order to display apps under a different company name? :/

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an app store, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as App Store account is about money & taxes, you have to create separate account per company name (can you create a bank account that can be accessed by two different companies? nope!).

Besides, new feature was introduced recently, App Transfer. So you can move your apps from company to company later, regardless initial submission.

Comment: Also, you cannot change the company name (as it appears in the App Store) once you set it. So, choose wisely. Hint, consider using only the distinguishable part of your company name, not your full company name. E.g. I dropped the words "Software" and "LLC" off mine.

Comment: @Marcus Adams, yep, correct addendum. App Store rules are quite strict so it's better to remember that you can't be sure you're allowed to change anything after you're public (for example, you also can't shorten the supported devices list if your next update requires some device-specific features).

Comment: Ok thanks, I applied for another iTunes account.

Answer (score 0):

Get the company to pay for its own account and then invite you as their developer.

If you are working for a company, that company is selling the app, not you.

Answer (score -1):

How do you have your company name as seller if its a individual account?